# Mysql - Subqueries w/ Counting Items

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables .. categories & deals. Ultimately, I want to do the following:

```
// foreach category
    // Display category title
    // show 3 entries in deals where it matches category title above, along with a link saying: "View (count) More Deals
```

Now, there are a couple of ways for me to do this:

```
// The "bad" way:
// foreach category
    // fetch count of total deals in this category
    // Display category title (once) 
        // Fetch & Display 3 deals
    // Display "View (count) more deals
// This is just quite a few queries for one page
```

The "other" way:

```
    SELECT count(deals.id),
           category.name as category_name,
           deal.name as deal_name
      FROM $db[ddd_deals] as deals
      JOIN $db[ddd_categories] 
        ON $db[ddd_categories].id = $db[ddd_deals].category_id
     WHERE deals.city_id = '$_SESSION[city_id]'
  ORDER BY $db[ddd_categories].name
```

The above does everything except display the number of deals in each category, and only display 3 deals per category

-Should I be selecting FROM the deals table (or from the categories table, then grab the deals?)

```
// I also tried the following. It returns what category and deal, but the count is off (it is only displaying 1):

  SELECT count(deals.id) as cc, 
         cat.name as cat_name, 
         deals.name as name 
    FROM ddd_categories as cat
    JOIN ddd_deals as deals 
      ON deals.category_id=cat.id
GROUP BY deals.id
ORDER BY cat.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick one, whether you group by deals.id or .., the order by came at an incorrect place.

```
select cc, cat_name, name from (
   SELECT count(deals.id) as cc, cat.name as cat_name, deals.name as name 
   FROM ddd_categories as cat
   JOIN ddd_deals as deals on deals.category_id=cat.id
   GROUP BY deals.id
)
ORDER BY xxx;
```

Comment: Neither one of these produce the results I need though. Basically, I want to display any 3 deals from each category under the category heading with a "view (count) more deals in this category). Should I do it the query intensive way? The code you posted above does everything except give me the total number of deals in each category..

Comment: If I use "Group By cat.id", i get the total number of deals in each category (cc), but it only displays 1 deal per category .. Any thoughts on another direction I could take this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY cat.id` instead of `deals.id`. Try to following:

```
SELECT count(deals.id) as cc, cat.name as cat_name, deals.name as name
FROM ddd_categories as cat JOIN ddd_deals as deals ON deals.category_id=cat.id
GROUP BY cat.id
```